# Outputing string data in graphics window

Tags: python, string

Below is the code I have so far for a simple Caesar cipher program, I am having issues trying to output the encoded data to the graphics window.

The program runs right. But the only output that appears on the screen is the first letter of the coded message, I need the whole coded message to appear on the graphics window.

I think it might be a problem with my loop but can't figure it out. I tried moving the loop around but that just gave two or three repetitions of the first letter.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
from graphics import*

def main():
    win = GraphWin("Caeser Cipher",500,500)
    win.setCoords(0.0,0.0,5.0,5.0)

    Text(Point(2,4.8),"Caesar Ciper").draw(win)

    label1 = Text(Point(1,4),"Please input file:").draw(win)

    inputFileName = Entry(Point(2.5,4,),20)
    inputFileName.draw(win)

    button1 = Text(Point(2.5,3.5),"Open").draw(win)
    Rectangle(Point(2.25,3.3),Point(2.75,3.7)).draw(win)

    label = Text(Point(1,2.5),"Please input step:")
    label.draw(win)
    inputstep = Entry(Point(2.5,2.5),20)
    inputstep.draw(win)


    button2 = Text(Point(2.5,2.0),"Encode").draw(win)
    Rectangle(Point(2.25,1.8),Point(2.75,2.2)).draw(win)

    button3 = Text(Point(4,1),"Save").draw(win)
    Rectangle(Point(3.75,0.8),Point(4.25,1.2)).draw(win)

    button4 = Text(Point(4,0.5),"Quit").draw(win)
    Rectangle(Point(3.75,0.3),Point(4.25,0.7)).draw(win)

    output2 = Text(Point(2.5,1.5),'  ')
    output2.setTextColor('blue')
    output2.draw(win)



    while True:
        P = win.getMouse()        

        if(P.getX()>2.25 and P.getX()<2.75 and P.getY()>3.3 and P.getY()<3.7):
            fnamein = inputFileName.getText()
            infile = open(fnamein, encoding='utf-16', mode='r')
            content = infile.read()
            output = Text(Point(2.5,3),100)
            output.setText(content)
            output.setTextColor('red')
            output.draw(win)
            #infile.close()

        if(P.getX()>2.25 and P.getX()<2.7 and P.getY()>1.8 and P.getY()<2.2):
            content.strip()
            words = content.split()
            inputstep1 = inputstep.getText()
            #print(inputstep1)

            encodedcontent = ' '
            for numStr in content:
                codeNum = ord(numStr)
                #print(codeNum)
                encodedcontent = chr(codeNum-eval(inputstep1))
                encodedcontent_ascii = ord(numStr)-int(inputstep1)
                #print(encodedcontent)
                #encodedcontent = encodedcontent + ''

                print(encodedcontent)

                if(encodedcontent_ascii)<ord('a'):
                    encodedcontent_ascii = encodedcontent_ascii + 26
                    #print(encodedcontent_ascii)
                '''if str.isalpha(encodedcontent):
                    encodedcontent = encodedcontent + chr(encodedcontent_ascii)
                else:
                    label.setTextColor('red')'''
                encodedcontent = encodedcontent + chr(encodedcontent_ascii)
                output2.setText(encodedcontent)


        if(P.getX()>3.75 and P.getX()<4.25 and P.getY()>0.8 and P.getY()<1.2):
            fnameout = 'encrypt.txt'
            data = encodedcontent
            outfile = open(fnameout,encoding='utf-16',mode='w')
            outfile.write(data)
            outfile.close()

        if(P.getX()>3.75 and P.getX()<4.25 and P.getY()>0.3 and P.getY()<0.7):
            win.close()



main()
```

Comment: You say "having issues"; could you be more specific? Errors (provide full traceback)? Unexpected outputs (provide inputs and expected and actual outputs)? Are there bits of the code you are sure are working you could remove?

Comment: Well the program runs right. But the only output that appears on the screen is the first letter of the coded message, I need the whole coded message to appear on the graphics window.I tried moving the loop around that just gave two or three repetitions of the first letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem lies in this loop:

```
encodedcontent = ' ' # initialise
for numStr in content:
    ...
    encodedcontent  = chr(codeNum-eval(inputstep1)) # overwrite
    ...   
    encodedcontent = encodedcontent + chr(encodedcontent_ascii) # add
```

`encodedcontent` will only be two characters at most, when presumably you want to build up the whole string.

More generally, putting all of your code into one place makes this difficult to debug. I suggest breaking it into smaller functions; at the very least, separate the encryption of a string out from the user interface.

Comment: new to the forum, will try to format better next time. thanks